How can I come up with an algorithm for splitting a series of numbers in given ratio so the rounded splits add up to the original number
I am trying to split a set of numbers into ratios (32%/68%) but would like to have an algorithm so that the rounded splits add up to the original number split. The straightforward approach does not do that.(22/48 vs 23/47)
Qty     32%     68%     Rounded Rounded   Adjusted Adjusted
10      3.2     6.8     3       7         3        7
10      3.2     6.8     3       7         3        7 
5       1.6     3.4     2       3         2        3
5       1.6     3.4     2       3         1        4
10      3.2     6.8     3       7         3        7
10      3.2     6.8     3       7         3        7    
5       1.6     3.4     2       3         2        3    
15      4.8     10.2    5       10        4        11
-------------------------------------------------------------   
70      22.4    47.6    23      47  70    21       49
        22      48 

The flexibility is that the splits need to be as close as possible to the target ratio if not exact.
So, if total after rounding comes out 1 more, that must be taken off, but from which  number?
The original number is 70, which splits 22.4/47.6. So which ratio is closer to 32/68 - is 22/48 or 23/47?
If 22/48 is better, then the extra can be removed from the first
number of one of the individual split.
But that mini split should be as close as possible to 32/68. It seems if an adjustment is to be made, the largest number is the one to pick for the adjustment to have minimum impact. So 5/10 could be 4/10 instead of 2/3 being 1/4.
The more important constraint, when the mini splits are added up, is that the split of the original number should be as close as possible to 32/68 and the original number must be produced by adding the mini splits.
Is it even possible that the rounded mini splits when added up will be less than the original number so instead of taking off something, something needs to be added?
Updated
I implemented the suggestion from Gabe Sechan (many thanks!) and the Adjusted columns add up to the original number. The original split is 21/49 which is not closer to 32/68 than 22/48. But I think without further optimization around the changing the order in which the numbers are processed, this is the solution that works.

If you have no flexibility around the small splits exactly meeting the target ratio then (in general) there's no solution, as your counterexample shows. If you do have flexibility, please describe it. E.g., would you prefer to minimize the number of mini-splits modified away from 32/68, or would you prefer to minimize the maximum absolute difference between any mini-split and its 32/68 target, or something else?

I think if you want to minimize the absolute difference you can just mathematically round the % values, because it is impossible to get exactly .5 with whole numbers and a 32/68 ratio.

@Dave I edited the problem to provide the flexibility

Keep track of the error-  the amount the rounding is off by.  For example if the number is 3.2 and gets rounded to 3, the error is -.2.  When the error is 1.6 and gets rounded to 2, the error is .4.  Each time you round, accumulate the error.  When the error gets big enough, adjust your rounding.  A simple way of doing that is adding the error to the actual number, then rounding the result.  So 3.2 with an error of .6 is 3.8 which rounds to 4.  Then your new error would be -.2 (you started with .6, then added -.8 leaving -.2).  However you can also choose other thresholds for when to adjust rounding, depending on how much you prefer to minimize the number of elements adjusted.
